# What 301 redirect would work for this string format?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an ecommerce store with the product URL format:
/categoryname/subcat1name/subcat2name/1450--my-widget

I will shorten it to:
/1450--my-widget

I can do the change within the ecommerce software, but I need to set up a mod rewrite redirect for the old URLs.

To avoid matching URLs for categories, content pages, etc, as well as product URLs of the new format, I need to match on all these conditions:

1. Does not contain the string "/info/"
2. Contains a slash, followed by 1 or more characters, followed by another slash, followed by 1 or more digits, followed by "--", followed by 1 or more characters

What directive would work?

EDIT:
More examples of matching and non matching strings

Matches for old product url:

```
/a-category/this-category/333--my-widget
/some-cat/34--widgetname
```

Non matches:

```
/1918--widgetcategory/
/info/12--about-us
/quick-order
/login?back=my-account
/2050--my-widgetname
```

Comment: Can you add few more valid and invalid examples in question.

Comment: Matches for old product url:
/a-category/this-category/333--my-widget
/some-cat/34--widgetname

Non matches:
/1918--widgetcategory/
/info/12--about-us
/quick-order
/login?back=my-account
/2050--my-widgetname

Comment: I don't know how to format a comment. I'm adding the info the the OP.

Comment: You can click on edit link below your question and provide this informaiton in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `301` redirect rule as your very first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(?!.*/info/).*/[^/]+/([0-9]+--[^/]+)/?$ /$1
```